# PHP strtotime always use 31 days months

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to calculate a duration that is expressed in human readable format (e.g. "3 months 10 days") and make it a timestamp.

My problem is that with my code uses `strtotime`, so if a month is 30 days long PHP interprets it as `0 months 30 days` instead of `31 days`.

What I need is to convert, for example, the string "1 month 10 days" to "31 days 10 days" (or "41 days").

```php
$strToTime = strtotime($pMsg);
$unixTimestamp = $strToTime - time();
$unixTimestampM = $unixTimestamp;
$months = floor((float)$unixTimestampM/2678400);
  if($months >= 1) {
    $unixTimestampM -= $months*2678400;
  }
$days = floor((float)$unixTimestampM/86400);
  if($days >= 1) {
    $unixTimestampM -= $days*86400;
  }
```

and so on for hours and minutes.

With the string "1 month 10 days" I expect the `$months` to be `1` and `$days` to be `10`, while, in certain periods of the year, `$days` become `9`.

Comment: Using `DateTime` and `DateInterval` objects would make this a lot easier and definitely more readable.

Comment: @jeroen ok but how should I do that?

Comment: Generate 2 `DateTime` objects and get the difference between the 2 with the `diff()` method. The resulting `DateInterval` object contains everything you need.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are able to use libraries, but carbon has a function specifically for this https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff